# How to recover data from ec2 instance on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rm, data-recovery

I have a small EC2 instance on which I have deploy Magento2. While I am trying to delete pub/static Unfortunately I have deleted pub folder. So my all products images are disappers.

Now I want to recover my pub folder. Is this possible? If Yes then HOW?

Note : I am using **small EC2 instance** and I have fired `rm -rf pub/` command.

Comment: Ehhhhhhh..... Sorry man, `rm` is pretty destructive. You can [try some of these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files).

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will try one of those.